# greater than or less than with an amount

Tags: sql

Sorry if this is basic but couldn't find this anywhere on stack overflow.

Ive created a temporary table and when i run the query it brings back alot of results. I need to narrow it down further by an amount difference between the 2 columns but im struggling to work out how to do it. The current query is:

```
select * from #mi where round(avalue,0) <> round(bvalue,0)
```

I basically want it to say <> 1000 (amounts are not the same but there is 1000 difference between the amounts i want to view)

Currently i am getting figures like this

avalue=10000 bvalue=10000.1

I need it to show as

avalue=10000 bvalue=20001 or bvalue=8999

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you are trying to do. Do you looking for  abs(round(avalue,0)-round(bvalue,0))>1000 ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you add a sample of your data in `#mi`-table? E.g. `SELECT TOP 10 * from #mi`?

Comment: Do you mean "exactly 1000 difference", "at least 1000 difference" or "at most 1000 difference"? Does it matter which one is the highest?

Comment: By the way, `<>` is "not equal"

Comment: Sorry, I did word this wrong. I currently have it set as 'not like' but i want it to say there must be at least 1000 difference between the totals from each row

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little unclear.  I think it is:

> amounts are not the same but there is 1000 difference between the amounts i want to view

Use `-` and `abs():

```
select *
from #mi
where abs(a.value - b.value) < 1000
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, Sorry, you are correct as i worded my question wrong. What you have stated is what im looking for. I couldnt get it to work but when combined like this it worked as expected. 

select * from #mi
where round(avalue,0) <> round(bvalue,0) and abs(a.value - b.value) > 1000

Answer (score 0):

you can use case when

```
 select t.*,
 case when round(avalue,0) <> round(bvalue,0) then round(bvalue+bvalue+1,0)
 from #mi t
```

Comment: Hi Zaynul, this didnt work for me and kept bringing back errors but i got the answer from gordon above so thanks anyway